# A panoply of queries about Magento databases

Tags: magento, filepath

Through which file are new customers created and saved in Magento databases?

Which function is used?

Please provide me with full path locations and function names.

Also tell me about customer groups. From where and through which files/functions do customer groups get saved in Magento?

How are customers and customer groups related?

How can I "catch" customer IDs and customer group IDs from those files?

I find the file through which **Magento saves New Customer**-:

```
/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
```

In the file **CustomerController.php**, there is a function **saveAction()** which saves a customer in Magento db. 
I wanted to know how to catch **Newly created customer's id(I guesss i.e. Entity Id in Customer_entity table for Magento db)**  from that CustomerController.php file.

I tried this but it won't work for me-"

```
$customer_data = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
```

Anybody knows how to catch customer id while creation of new customer???

Answer (score 2):

Try to search here:

```
Mage_Customer_AccountController->createPostAction
```

Well class name means

(root)/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountControlller

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Customer_GroupController
```

Comment: Ok..Thanks... what about Customer Group...Where should I get file for Customer Group?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the AccountController.php at app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers, it will give you an idea how customer registration is processed. 
Basically an instance of Mage_Customer_Model_Customer is created,  proper data is assigned to it (collected from a post form on the registraton form or received via a webservice call) and the model is saved. The internal Magento mechanics work to put this data in proper db tables.
See also create function of the Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api class.

customer groups are created in Mage_Adminhtml_Customer_GroupController->saveAction(), the model being used is Mage_Customer_Model_Group

Comment: ok..N what about Customer Group...Where should I get file for Customer Group?

Answer (score 1):

actually customer group is assigned from backend,by default general group is selected for customer group, if you want to get customer groups then you can use this code `Mage::helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Search for this file

```
/YourProject/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

Search for this function name

```
public function createPostAction() //Magento saves New Customer
```

This above mentioned function is responsible for new customer registration.

```
print_r($this->getRequest()->getPost()); //get all the post data
print_r($session);                       //get all the session data
```